# Call VB.NET method via .dll from C# program

Tags: c#, vb.net

my code contain a VB.Net Class that i have built into a .dll that will be used inside a C#-WPF program, the problem is when i try to call any function from that .dll i get an error saying:

> the methode have some invalide argument

my vb code :

```
Public Function PerformDCVoltageMeasurement_niDMM(ByRef dDMM_Reading As Double) As Boolean
    Try

        Call Initialize_niDMM(GetInstrumentAddress(sPXIInstrument).DeviceAddress, DC_VOLTS, 60, 100, 3.5)
        Dim dTemp As Double
        'Start the acquisition
        NIpxiDMM.Initiate()
        NIpxiDMM.Fetch(-1, dTemp)
        dDMM_Reading = dTemp
        NIpxiDMM.Dispose()
        Return True

    Catch
        gsCurrentPXIDeviceAddress_dmm = ""
        NIpxiDMM.Dispose()
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

and my C#-wpf code :

```
SwitchExecutive.SwitchExecutive SwitchControl = new SwitchExecutive.SwitchExecutive();
Double Jg;
SwitchControl.PerformDCVoltageMeasurement_niDMM(out Jg);
```

The last statement gives an error

> Methode have some invalid argument

Comment: `ByRef` is `ref` in c#, not `out`.

Comment: Look at the intellisense which will show you the proper method signature, or search the web for the **exact** compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't like you calling the method with an `out` argument, since VB.net doesn't support them. Try calling it as:

```
SwitchControl.PerformDCVoltageMeasurement_niDMM(ref Jg);
```

Comment: thank you Anduril, it solve my problem ^^